# TypeError: readImpl(...) is not a function

Tags: purescript

I'm getting

```
TypeError: readImpl(...) is not a function
```

from compiled code, and I'm not using FFI nor `unsafeCoerce`, which usually lead to these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `rm -rf output`, sometimes the incremental compilation is faulty.